# Kotlin Flow How to combine two flows and only emit the result when the first flow sends element

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-flow

There are two flows: FlowA and FlowB.

I want to combine them and get the latest element from FlowA and the latest element from FlowB only when FlowA emits an element. It's like combining FlowA and FlowB but only triggers the combined flow when FlowA emits an element.

Answer (score 4):

If `flowA` doesn't contain repeated elements, or if you're ok to "not trigger" on repeated elements of A, you could achieve what you want with [zip](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/zip.html) and [distinctUntilChangedBy](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/distinct-until-changed-by.html) like this:

```kotlin
val flowA = flowOf("a", "b", "c")
val flowB = flowOf(1, 2, 3)

val resultFlow = flowA.zip(flowB)
                      .distinctUntilChangedBy { (a, _) -> a }
                      .map { (a, b) -> TODO("combine a and b") }
```

Another option is making a `StateFlow` out of B and accessing the latest value when you need it (but it requires a scope to collect B in the state, so it makes this code half hot):

```kotlin
val flowA = flowOf("a", "b", "c")
val flowB = flowOf(1, 2, 3)

val stateB = flowB.stateIn(someScope)
val resultFlow = flowA.map { a -> 
    val b = stateB.value
    TODO("combine a and b")
}
```

Comment: Thanks. "combine" will be better in my case for the first option and if some adjacent elements are the same in flowA, it will not work

Comment: @星星瑶 but `combine` will also trigger on B's changes, so it won't do what you want. Yeah the solution with `distinctUntilChangedBy` only works if you don't want to trigger on repeated elements of A. I'll add a note about that.

Comment: I mean I used  combine with distinctUntilChangedBy. Thanks

Comment: Ah ok, but then you will run your "combination" code even on events where you normally don't want to trigger. I didn't think this was an option, but yeah this may work for you :)